# When to use Internal app sharing vs. Internal testing (google play)?

Tags: android, google-play

The descriptions for the two seem incredibly similar:

- [Internal app sharing](https://play.google.com/console/about/internalappsharing/): Quickly share app bundles and APKs with your internal team using a link
- [Internal testing](https://play.google.com/console/about/internal-testing/): Quickly distribute your builds to a small set of trusted testers without the need to wait for app reviews. Integrate with build qualification processes before promoting to more users.

It seems like they both:

- Support up to 100 internal testers
- Don't require review

When should someone opt for one or the other?

Thanks in advance! - An android dev noob

Comment: Related: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?_ga=2.115076814.896976354.1631343816-805024323.1593367602

Answer (score 3):

There are some differences although the documentation isn't very clear.
In my experience some features like [In-App Review](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review) can NOT be tested using Internal testing, only through Internal app sharing.

Also the distribution process is different, for Internal app sharing I had to activate the developer settings in Google Play on my device (tapping the Play Store version 7 times) in order to be able to download the application, this wasn't necessary when using Internal testing.

See for more info [Internal testing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334) and [Internal app sharing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679).

Answer (score 1):

There are subtle difference with uploading apps to be tested.  First one is “app testing” which contains different environments (beta, production, internal).  these help test the actual release process to users that search in the store

Internal app sharing, is actually different, this allows you or any uploaders or testers you specify to upload builds of an app.  You can then share a shareable link with testers and they will be able to download the app via google play.  For users to use this though they will need to enable “internal app testing” on your device.  Another difference here is there are no validation requirements to use internal app sharing (I.E can upload any version, any permissions, no store listing fields need be added etc..), versus uploading to a testing environment above

Welcome to use, either but the testing environments require specific incremental versions, as well as have permission requirements, privacy policy url crap and stuff that is similar to what is required for a build to go live on the store.

Comment: I am struggling to understand the use case for "Internal App Sharing". The major difference is that "App Sharing" has virtually no restrictions or verifications on upload (versions, name, etc). This is perfect during early development. AND YET, Google doesn't allow to use "App Sharing" until and app has been published... wtf. What's the point of it AFTER the app has been polished enough to publish?